# What to do when RemotingConfiguration.Configure fails?

Tags: .net, remoting

I have a Web Site and Windows Service that communicates through a single call server object.  My remoting setup is handled through config files.

Normally, if I instantiated the object using new() I get a "TransparentProxy" back.  Then when I called a method if the Windows Service was running it would work and if it wasn't I would get a RemotingException.

Today, I'm noticing in our production environment that when new() is being called a local object is being created.  What appears to happened is that "RemotingConfiguration.Configure" which I call in the Web Site's "Application Start" event in the Global.asax file.  The exception was:

"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" which had an inner exception of "RemotingException: "Failed to create an IPC Port:"  Access is denied.".  The method that threw the error was "IpcServerChannel.StartListening".

I've never seen this error during development and the app has been running for about a month in production.  Why would this error occur?  I'm pretty confident the real reason isn't an access issue.

Thanks,

Chris McKinnon

Answer (score 0):

Any changes in the .Net version, either installed or set in the properties of the Web Site? 
Any changes in the config files? Even small ones? [This link](http://adamhouldsworth.blogspot.com/2009/12/net-remoting-ipc-configuration-returns.html) shows the effects of small errors.

The other scenario to look into is when the service is shut down 
and started again while the client is still active. The service attempts to 
re-register the IpcServerChannel using the same portName and name as the 
previous time. [See this link](http://www.cetix.de/DotNetNews/Thread99188-Cannot_create_server_connection_when_client_already_created.aspx) for the details.